# Deleted my WordPress files from a directory, whole PHP config is messed up now

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, cloudflare, 500-error

It was working fine before I deleted all of my WordPress files from example2.com/blog. I now get Error 500 for every page and website I try to access on the server. I enabled HTTPS with CloudFlare before I deleted the files, so that could be part of the problem.  Apache error and access logs show no errors. Fail2ban does not show it is banning my IP.

This is the only conf I have enabled:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName college.example1.com
    ServerAlias college.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com/college

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example1.com/college">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example1.com
    ServerAlias dev.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com/dev

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example1.com/dev">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pma.example1.com
    ServerAlias pma.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin

    <Directory "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com/master

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example1.com/master">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/master

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example2/master">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    Alias /blog /var/www/html/example2/blog
    <Directory "/var/www/html/example2/blog">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example2.com
    ServerAlias dev.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/dev

    <Directory "/var/www/html/example2/dev">
        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example4.example3.com
    ServerAlias dev.example4.example3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps/example4/dev

    <Directory "/var/www/html/apps/example4/dev">
        Require all granted

        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example4.example3.com
    ServerAlias example4.example3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps/example4/master

    <Directory "/var/www/html/apps/example4/master">
        Require all granted

        MaxMindDBEnable On
        MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
        MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

        SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowCountry

        Require env AllowCountry
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error (debug) log:

```
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.132058 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6517] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] AH01626: authorization result of Require env AllowCountry: granted
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.132243 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6517] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.133029 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6517] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] AH01626: authorization result of Require env AllowCountry: granted
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.133286 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6517] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.138691 2017] [:error] [pid 6517] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Nov 30 02:58:21.138952 2017] [:error] [pid 6517] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21611] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/example2/blog/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: If the apache error log shows no error increase the log level.

Comment: Deleting php files from the webspace only would not have such an impact. Is it possible you missed the hidden file .htaccess and that some directives in there point to now missing files or directories?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Filezilla is enabled to show all hidden files. Every file in the directory was deleted.

Comment: Many things can cause a browser to show a 500 error. The only way to track them down is to find then in your error logs which will show the exact cause. Until you do that there is little we can do to help. My initial suggestion is to recover from a known good backup.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Error log with debug level posted in OP.

Comment: @user430214 Log posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that I had `auto_prepend_file` set to `wordfence-waf.php` in php.ini, which was listed in the error log as inaccessible by PHP. Commenting out the line and reloading Apache fixed the problem.